# Count number of elements that increase or decrease by a factor of 10 with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

```
  #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int factorsOf10(int arr[], int value)
{
    int count = 0;
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] * 10 = arr[j])
                count++;
            else
                return(arr[] + 1, value);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,10,20 };
    int result = factorsOf10(arr, 0);
    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have done so far but it went wrong. Can anybody give me some idea, please?
I need to compute recursively the number of consecutive elements that increase or decrease by a factor of 10.
For example:

```
factorsOf10([1, 10, 20], 0) → 1
factorsOf10([100, 10, 20, 200], 0) → 2
factorsOf10([1000, 100, 10, 1, 10], 0) → 4
factorsOf10([10, 20, 33, 340], 0) → 0
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(0)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I just want to find the size of array first by using it.

Comment: Arrays degenerate to pointers in function calls. A consequence is that the length of the array is lost. You need to pass an extra parameter to your function `factorsOf10` to explicitly tell it the length of the array.

Comment: Or even better: Drop the legacy from C alltogether and use `std::vector` instead. `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(0)` will be a compile time constant, because `arr` is in actual fact a pointer and no array.

Comment: Ha! I hadn't even noticed this was C++ and not C.

Comment: I just edited my code but using C++. But when I do the same thing with java it went wrong
public static int factorsOf10(int[] array, int value)
    {

        if (value <= 0) 
            return 0;
        else return (array[0] == 10 * array[1] || array[1] == 10 * array[0]) + factorsOf10(array + 1 , value - 1);
    }

Comment: Can you help me to fix it, please?